# stemming words in python

Tags: python, nlp, stemming

I'm using this code to stem words, here is how it works, first there's a list of suffixes, the program checks if the word has the ending same as the one in the list if positive it removes the suffix, however, when I run the code I get this result:

```
suffixes = ['ing']
def stem(word):
for suff in suffixes:
    return word[:-len(suff)]

stem ('having')
print (stem)
```

Comment: *"the program checks if the word has the ending same as the one in the list"* - no, it doesn't... Also, there's more to stemming than just stripping `'ing'` - if you need to do this, look into `nltk`.

Comment: anmol_uppal wrote correct answer, but as jonsrharpe suggests, I would take a look on the nltk or this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stemming/1.0

Comment: Actually I'm writing a stemmer for Persian Language and this is only a part of the code which doesn't work and I don't want to use NLTK for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each suffix in the given list you can check if the given word ends with any of the given suffixes, if yes the remove the suffix, else return the word.

```
suffixes = ['ing']
def stem(word):
    for suff in suffixes:
        if word.endswith(suff):
            return word[:-len(suff)]

    return word

print(stem ('having'))
>>> hav
```

Comment: This will only check the first suffix before returning. And there's a similar problem in the list comprehension.

Comment: I get syntax error ==>
    print stem ('having')
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you using Python3 @adelrahimi ?

Comment: Edited @adelrahimi, I still can't understand the meaning of down vote ?

Comment: @anmol_uppal I ddn't downvote your answer, I don't even have enough reputation to be able to vote on Stackoverflow, anyways, how can i use this code in python 3?

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at Porter Stemmer (http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/), there's one for Python too.